# Crawling through multiple excel files, match and copy data to master file

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have written a macro, that is crawling through multiple excel files, which are all identical in terms of structure (columns, but row content may differ; there is a "key" though) and matching and copying the data into a master file. But with an increasing number of files the duration of macro execution is growing longer and longer, so maybe someone has a more efficient solution available?

```
Sub DataCrawler()
 
    On Error GoTo HandleError
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim objectFileSys As Object
    Dim objectGetFolder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Set objectFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objectGetFolder = objectFileSys.GetFolder("pathName") ' location of folder with files
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0
   
    ' macro opens one file after another and checks for every key, if data is available
   
    For Each file In objectGetFolder.Files
        Dim sourceFiles As Workbook
        Set sourceFiles = Workbooks.Open(file.Path, True, True)
       
        Dim lookUp As Range
        Dim searchRange As Range
       
        For i = 10 To 342 ' number of rows with key in master file
            Set lookUp = Cells(i, 31)
            Set searchRange = sourceFiles.Worksheets("tableName").Range("AE:AJ")
            ' if cell in master file related to the key is empty, copy data
            If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 35)) Then
                lookUp.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(lookUp, searchRange, 2, False) 
                lookUp.Offset(0, 2).Value = Application.VLookup(lookUp, searchRange, 3, False) 
                lookUp.Offset(0, 3).Value = Application.VLookup(lookUp, searchRange, 4, False)
                lookUp.Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.VLookup(lookUp, searchRange, 5, False) 
                lookUp.Offset(0, 5).Value = Application.VLookup(lookUp, searchRange, 6, False) 
            
            ' if cell in master file related to the key is already filled, skip
            Else
                
            End If
        Next
       
        sourceFiles.Close False
        Set sourceFiles = Nothing
    Next
HandleError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: A single `Application.Match()` to find the row for the "key" then copying the content as an array would be faster, but it's difficult to say what impact that would have on the overall run time: that would depend on how many files you're opening and what the performance of that aspect of the process is like.

Comment: I would go with MQuery code with a filter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single `Application.Match()` to find the row for the "key", then copying the content as an array would be faster, but it's difficult to say what impact that would have on the overall run time. That would depend on how many files you're opening, and what the performance of that aspect of the process is like.

```vb
Sub DataCrawler()
 
    Dim objectFileSys As Object, objectGetFolder As Object
    Dim file As Object, searchRange As Range, i As Long
    Dim m, wsData As Worksheet, wbSource As Workbook
    
    On Error GoTo HandleError
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup") 'for example
    
    Set objectFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objectGetFolder = objectFileSys.GetFolder("pathName")
    
    For Each file In objectGetFolder.Files
        
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(file.Path, True, True)
        Set searchRange = wbSource.Worksheets("tableName").Columns("AE")
        
        For i = 10 To 342 ' number of rows with key in master file
            If IsEmpty(wsData.Cells(i, 35)) Then
                m = Application.Match(wsData.Cells(i, 31).Value, searchRange, 0)
                If Not IsError(m) Then
                    wsData.Cells(i, 32).Resize(1, 5).Value = _
                       searchRange.Cells(m).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
        wbSource.Close False
    Next file

HandleError:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! I'll try that one tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: OK - FYI made a small edit to the line that copies the data.

Comment: I changed my code today accordingly and it works like a charm. Run time is significantly lower than before. Thanks!